# WinFormsControlLibrary in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `windowformscontrol` library to capture a image and it is referring a dll "***test.dll***".

And when i am using the `windowformscontrol` library in my `Asp.net` app its throwing an error while running in explorer..

```
Exception : Unable to load the assembly test.dll
```

plz resolve my issue.

Comment: Maybe giving us the message of the error would be a good start :)))

Comment: How are you using it ? Do you really have the dll in your deployed folder ? Do you have the permissions set else it would be difficult for it to capture the image ! !

Comment: ya added that dll by addreference and also copied it in my web_app root directory

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not use Windows dll on Web. See if these posts help you solve your problem
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx

Comment: ya i followed the same procedure but the windowforms library refering another dll wasn't working in aspx page .

Comment: Check if that dll exists in your bin folder, if not and is a dot net dll then copy it to your bin folder

Comment: dll is existed even though throwing exception ...unable load assembly

Comment: i hope bot the dll exist one is of winform and another which winform refers. If yes then please share full text of err

Comment: Exception Text : Could not load file or assembly "Assebly name" Version=1.0.2395.24959 ,Culture=neutral ,publick key Token = null'or one of its dependencies .Failed to grant minimum permission request.(Exceptin from HRESULT:0*80131417)

Comment: It's because of security reasons its not getting loaded, try giving rights to Asp.net, Network Service user or if possible give full permissions to Everyone user. Though its a risk affair and it can let the doors open for hackers. So do it wisely!!!

Comment: how to do that ..can u plz tel me

Comment: can't list all the steps something like this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-setting-folder-permissions-6-of-12

Comment: thank u...but by giving permission also it not working..I don't hav IIS installed on my system ,is that an Issue

Comment: IIS may not be a problem, i thought you have hosted your site in it.

Comment: no ,i am just running it from my E drive not from c:/wwroot/Inetpubs